# html - how to make images stay on certain part of background

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have a background image with the size in CSS being cover, so it resizes as the browser window resizes. but when i place images, how can i position them so that they stay in a certain place according to the background? i tried using left:...px and top:...px and i know why that isn't working, because when i resize the window it will stay at that position away from the left and top, but what is the solution? i want the images to resize proportionally to how big the window/background is and stay in a certain location on the background

Comment: you may need to use percentages rather than px

Comment: @Pete how would i do that while still being able to keep the images in the same spot relative to the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use absolute positioning with %'s

**HTML:**

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#foo{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:20%;
}
```

For the position you can use absolute, fixed, or relative depending on what suites best.

Fixed: relative to browser window;

Relative: relative to natural position

Absolute: relative to first positioned ancestor

Comment: actually now when i resize the window left and right, the images resize, but they don't stay in the same spot relative to the background...

Comment: Could you create a JSfiddle of the relevant mark up and CSS? So I can try to help more.  Create here http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like the background image to resize but keep a particular element in the same vertical position, one way to do this is to use the calc() function inside the background-position property with background-size set to 100%.

For example:

```
background-image: url('your image');
background-position: top calc(200px - 20vw) right;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

As the image expands the element inside the image that you want to keep in the same vertical position will naturally get larger and move downwards. The negative viewport value inside the calculation compensates for this vertical downward movement whereas the first value sets the elements vertical position. Adjust the values inside the calc() function until you are satisfied with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem (maybe you should try to put some codes or create a jsfiddle).

However I think you should take a look at the css3 [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property.

I guess [this sample from W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size2) is what you need.